# Filter obs in a tibble where variable contains any substring from another vector

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to filter obs (bar and paz) in a tibble where variable contains any substring from some vector.

```r
my_letters <- c("a", "b", "c")
tibble::tibble(a = c("foo", "bar", "paz")) |>
  dplyr::filter(any(purrr::map_lgl(my_letters, ~stringr::str_detect(a, .x))))
#> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
#> i Input `..1` is `any(purrr::map_lgl(my_letters, ~stringr::str_detect(a, .x)))`.
#> x Result 1 must be a single logical, not a logical vector of length 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Have simplified things a bit, not sure how essential it is that you need to use the `my_letters` vector

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


df <- tibble(a = c("foo", "bar", "paz"))

  filter(df, str_detect(a, "[abc]"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   a    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 bar  
#> 2 paz
```

Or if you need  to do this programmatically with `my_letters`

```
my_letters <- paste0("[", paste(my_letters, collapse = ""), "]")

  filter(df, str_detect(a, my_letters))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   a    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 bar  
#> 2 paz
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The vector, I just demonstrated there by creating a simple one. It is potentially a variable, so yes. I'll try the second one thanks.

Comment: if this answers the question please accept and upvote, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `base R`

```
subset(df, grepl('[abc]', a))
```